# Faithful representation of a finite group over reals

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/77325/finite-groups-with-faithful-real-two-dimensional-representation

Suppose $\pi :G \rightarrow SL_2(\mathbb{R})$ is a faithful representation of a finite group $G$, then I want to prove that $G$ must be cyclic.

I knew that every finite subgroup of $GL_2(\mathbb{R})$ is conjugate to a subgroup of the orthogonal group $O_2(\mathbb{R})$ and that $G \cong \pi (G) \leq SL_2(\mathbb{R})$ but I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: see here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/200354/faithful-representation-implies-group-is-cyclic  - this question is a duplicate